# Symfony How to Edit Array of Entity Objects each in their own Separate Form

Tags: symfony, twig

I have an array of entity objects that I queried from the database. I want to render each object in it's own form on the same page with a vote submit button next to each object. I have no problem rendering them in the twig template, but what will the update action look like? I can't seem to figure it out from there. If there is an error in the validation of the object I'm trying to update, how do I render all the forms again on the same page with the errors next to the correct form? I'm having problems since it is an array of forms.

This is the action to render the forms:

```
 public function showVotingAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $votes = $em->getRepository('PresidentialDebateBundle:Vote')
->findAll();

    $forms = array();

            foreach ($votes as $vote) {
          $forms[] = $this->createForm(
            new VoteType(),
            $vote,
            array(
                'action' => $this->generateUrl('vote'),
                'method' => 'POST',
            )
        )->createView();
    }

                return $this->render(
        'PresidentialDebateBundle:Voting:showVoting.html.twig',
        array(
            'forms' => $forms
        )
    );
}
```

And this is the twig template:

```
{% for form in forms %}
{{ form_start(form) }}
{{ form_errors(form) }}   
{{ form.vars.value.monthlySnack }}
{{ form.vars.value.count }}
{{ form_widget(form.vote) }}
<input type="hidden" name="voteId" value="{{ form.vars.value.id }}">
<input type="hidden" name="snackId" value="{{ form.vars.value.monthlySnack.snack }}">
{{ form_end(form) }}
{% endfor %}
```

And this is the action I'm having problems with and can't figure out how to update each row individually:

```
public function voteAction(Request $request)
    {

    $voteId = $request->request->get("voteId");
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $vote = $em->getRepository("PresidentialDebateBundle:Vote")->find($voteId);

$form = $this->createForm(new VoteType(),$vote,array(
'action' => $this->generateUrl('vote'),
'method' => 'POST',));


if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {

$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isValid()) {


$vote->setCount($vote->getCount() + 1);
$em->flush();

return $this->redirectToRoute('show_voting');// redirect when done

} 

}



return $this->render(
'PresidentialDebateBundle:Voting:showVoting.html.twig',
array('form' => $form->createView())
);

}
```

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html

Comment: But how do I add a submit button next to each form row. Won't this render each form collectively as 1 form?

Comment: You can add a submit button to the voter form type.  And yes all the forms will be submitted when any of them are pressed but that is fine.  All of the elements you changed will be linked to the voter entity and be updated accordingly.